# Is it possible to use IPv4 prefixes (subnets) as "public IPs" in the network interface of an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, prefix, ipv4, elastic-ip

I transferred a /24 subnet (256 IPs) to AWS via BYOIP and I would like to assign some of these IPs to EC2 instances.

I know it is possible to assign a small subset directly to the instance's network interface as Elastic IPs, but I'm looking for a way to assign a larger quantity at once, for example a /28 (16 IPs) or more.

Is it possible to use IPv4 prefix delegation (as in the link below) as "public IPs" for outbound traffic?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-prefix-eni.html

If not, is there any other way to achieve this?